# XPath not recognised in page object model in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, xpath, page-objects

xpath not recognised in page object model in webdriver.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//td[contains (text(),'xxx')]")
public WebElement topMenu;

topMenu.click();
```

> Error: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains (text(),'xxx')]"}

I'm using page object model in WebDriver.
Any suggestions?

So this is my actual code of my program

```
public WebElement userName;
public WebElement password;
public WebElement id;
@FindBy(xpath = "//td[contains (text(),'Procurement')]")
public WebElement topMenu;
```

Comment: I expect your HTML to contain an excerpt `<td>Procurement</td>`. Is it there?

Comment: @dzieciou Now i have edited the error

Comment: Can you then provide also your HTML document, or at least its relevant part?

Comment: i dont have any html documents it is displayed in my eclipse console

Comment: Well, I guess it is evaluated over some Web page (HTML), when you run your test with your PageObject, right?

Comment: @dzieciou i have edited with relevant part as it couldn't recognise, can i use it with wait method there?

Comment: There might be muliple reasons for your test to fail: (1) incorrect XPath, (2) timing issues, etc. and it is hard to tell which one is a case for you, without seeing the page you're testing. Google returns a number of possible root causes for "enable to locate element".

Comment: @dzieciou many thanks for you as i would let it go by wait in my programme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this.  The first is that you need to be sure that your xPath is correct.  One way to validate that is to use a tool like Firefinder (a firefox extension for firebug).  Navigate to your page and be sure the element you need is present and then hit f12 and go to the FireFinder section.  Enter in the xpath you are using and see if it can be found.

Assuming your xpath is correct then you might want to investigate using an explicit wait if from some reason you are waiting on the page element to load.

Example:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(topMenu));
    topMenu.click();
```

I would suspect though this is failing because your xPath is not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Can you find it if you use the .Text and then clicking it if it matches?

```
String Expectedtext = "Procurement"
String ProcurementButtonText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td")).Text;


if (ProcurementButtonText == Expectedtext)
{
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td")).click()
}
```

Comment: sure user i wil make your suggestion.